# Flexbox with resized height image keeps the original width

Tags: css, image, flexbox, resize, tailwind-css

Changed the height of the flexbox (h-40) and set the image height to full (h-full). In this case the height of the image changes and fills the entire container, keeps the aspect ratio which is good and expected.
But the container div (with blue background) does not change in width, just in height.

How can I make this div to be as same width as the image?

https://codepen.io/lordjancso/pen/eYKOVRN

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-row justify-around h-40">
    <div class="bg-blue-700">
        <img class="h-full" src="https://picsum.photos/500/700">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-blue-700">
        <img class="h-full" src="https://picsum.photos/500/700">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `w-fit` [utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width) on the images' container. `w-fit`, which is the `width: fit-content;` class in CSS, will use the available space, but never more than [max-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content).

```html
<div class="flex flex-row justify-around h-40 w-fit">
    <div class="bg-blue-700">
        <img class="h-full" src="https://picsum.photos/500/700">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-blue-700">
        <img class="h-full" src="https://picsum.photos/500/700">
    </div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/qrV2Kg5wIn)